# Can I have objects inside an object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

So I want to have objects in objects e.g.

```
 1. var Parent={
 2.    var Child1 = {
 3.       funct:function(){
 4.          ...
 5.       },
 6.       funct2:function(){
 7.          ...
 8.       }
 9.    },
 10.   var Child2 = {
 11.      funct3:function(){
 12.         ...
 13.      }
 14.   }
 15. }
```

so I can do something like Parent.Child1.funct() ...etc.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: As @Guilherme Sehn said, you have to follow object's syntax. You can have pretty much anything inside an object. It's just another key/value pairs or properties.

Comment: Ohh, great! I thought it was more complicated :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, but you'll need to respect the object syntax.

```
var Parent = {
    Child1: {
        funct: function() {
        }
    },
    Child2: {
        funct: function() {
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Sure, it's just another property:

```
var Parent={
  Child1: {
    funct: function() {}
  },
  Child2: {
    funct: function() {}
  }
}

Parent.Child1.funct();
```